# List comprehension for multiplying each string in a list by numbers from given range

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying out the list comprehensions. But I got stuck when I tried to write a list comprehension for the following code.

```
a = ['x','y','z']
result = []
for i in a:
    for j in range(1,5):
        s = ''
        for k in range(j):
            s = s + i
        result.append(s)
result
```

output for this is:

```
['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz']
```

Is it even possible to write a list comprehension for this code? if it is how would you write it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here it is:

```
[ x * i for x in ['x','y','z'] for i in range(1,5)  ]
```

The result:

```
['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz']
```

Comment: ya, its a more elegant way to do that. But what if I have a situation where I have multiple loops and a local variable in between and an append operation outside of the inner loop, what would the list comprehension look like then?.....I guess in that situation using regular loops would be a better option

Comment: @Sri991 IMHOl, list comprehension in python is a great tool, but it's sometimes overused - which leads to the creation of code which is difficult to understand and debug. In these cases, regular loops are often a better choice. Another alternative is using intermediate steps, with meaningful variable and function names.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['x','y','z']
result = []
result+=[i*j for i in a for j in range(1,5)]
result
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

Possible!!!!

```py
>>> a = ['x','y','z']
>>> sorted([i*j for j in range(1,5) for i in a])
['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz']
```